# Teradata distance between two geo-coordinates using ST_SPHERICALDISTANCE

Tags: sql, geospatial, teradata

I have read that in Teradata Version 13 and onward you can use ST_SPHERICALDISTANCE for calculating geo-distance.
I written a simple test query in Teradata:

```
Select
Cast('POINT(-35.0000, 150.0000)' As ST_GEOMETRY) As location1,
Cast('POINT(-35.0000, 149.0000)' As ST_GEOMETRY) As location2,
location1.ST_SPHERICALDISTANCE(location2) As Distance_In_km
```

But received following error:

> Teradata row not delivered (trget): 13
>   OGRGeometryFactoryX::createFromWkt failed.

Is this an issue with the query or configuration?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the comma within the point definition :)

```
Select
Cast('POINT(-35.0000 150.0000)' As ST_GEOMETRY) As location1,
Cast('POINT(-35.0000 149.0000)' As ST_GEOMETRY) As location2,
location1.ST_SPHERICALDISTANCE(location2) As Distance_In_km
```

Btw, another  way to create a point:

```
NEW ST_GEOMETRY('POINT(-35.0000 150.0000)')
```

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth the query works now!
But one thing I found is that ST_SPHERICALDISTANCE didn't return the distance in unit of km or m. How would I convert to km?
See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lat-35+lon149+to+lat-35+lon150

Comment: In order to find distance in km, the value from ST_SPHERICALDISTANCE() has to be divided by 1000.

Comment: Also inside 'Point()' the values are Longitude then Latitude, unlike the traditional way of writing geo-coordinates.