# How to check the vicinity of a specific address and select other addresses in that area?

Tags: sql, teradata

| owner | coor x | coor y | coor x min | coor x max | coor y min | coor y max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| paul | 22,2 | 52 | 22 | 22,4 | 51,8 | 52,2 |
| john | 22,4 | 51,8 | 22,2 | 22,6 | 51,6 | 52 |
| john | 22,9 | 51,6 | 22,7 | 23,1 | 51,4 | 51,8 |
| paul | 21,5 | 52,4 | 21,3 | 21,7 | 52,2 | 52,6 |
| greg | 21,7 | 50,3 | 21,5 | 21,9 | 50,1 | 50,5 |

I have a database (house_owner, coordinate x, coordinate y). I attach a simplified view of the table. I want to select all the addresses where owner is john and addresses that are nearby john. So i want to select first 3 rows beacuse paul's home is close to first john's home (second row). I know that code is wrong because those selects returns a values in different order so it cant work but i dont know how to write that. Also the definition or "nearby" should be write better but "-0.002" and "+0.002" in coordinates is enough for me. Later I added columns to my database "x min" "x max" "y min" "y max". These columns define the range of the area but I don't know if that will help.

```
SELECT * FROM houses_table WHERE ((CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10,6)) BETWEEN 
       (SELECT CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) - 0.002 
        FROM houses_table  WHERE house_owner IN ('john')) 
       AND (SELECT CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) + 0.002 
            FROM houses_table  
            WHERE house_owner IN ('john'))) AND (CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10,6)) BETWEEN
       (SELECT CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) - 0.002 
        FROM houses_table 
        WHERE house_owner IN ('john'))
   AND (SELECT CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10,6)) + 0.002 
        FROM houses_table 
        WHERE house_owner IN ('john'))));
```

Comment: you should take a look at this, and let teradata caculate the distance https://stackoverflow.com/a/39762236/5193536  and the you can select all that are "near"

Answer (score 0):

Agree using Teradata Geospatial is likely the better approach. But to keep the related values together, use a subquery / CTE and join:

```
WITH Owner_houses (
SELECT CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) - 0.002 as xmin
       CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) + 0.002 as xmax
       CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) - 0.002 as ymin
       CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10, 6)) + 0.002 as ymax
            FROM houses_table  
            WHERE house_owner IN ('john')
)
SELECT * FROM houses_table 
       JOIN Owner_houses
       ON  CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10,6)) BETWEEN ymin and ymax
       AND CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10,6)) BETWEEN xmin and xmax
;
```

Or if the min/max values are already in your table, just

```
WITH Owner_houses (
SELECT xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
            FROM houses_table  
            WHERE house_owner IN ('john')
)
SELECT * FROM houses_table 
       JOIN Owner_houses
       ON  CAST(coor_y AS DECIMAL(10,6)) BETWEEN ymin and ymax
       AND CAST(coor_x AS DECIMAL(10,6)) BETWEEN xmin and xmax
;
```